# FIND duplicates in Ansible Dictionary

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I need to check that the same port isn't used in two sub-dictionaries.

```
my_dict:
  first:
    redis:
      port: 1234
  second:
    redis:
      port: 1235
  third:
    redis:
      port: 1234
```

In a task I can use the following:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ my_dict | dict2items | map(attribute="value.redis.port") | list }}'
```

This returns:

```
['1234', '1235', '1234']
```

What I need, is some way to filter only the duplicates. So I get:

```
['1234', '1234']
```

Returned.

Basically, I need to check that the ports aren't duplicated, and if they are apply a fail task that checks, and shows which items are causing the conflict.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Jinja2 set filters](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters)

Comment: I don't see one of them that show ONLY DUPLICATES.

Answer (score 0):

The filters that @stacksonstacks linked to are not helpful in this specific case because the population of ports is *always* the same, it's only their number which changes: `set([1,2,2,2]) == set([1,2])` is always `True`

So what we really want is to *group by* the port, and look for children of length greater than 1. Then, we can extract the name of the key that caused the collisions in order to report them.

```
tasks:
- set_fact:
    bogus: >-
      {%- for port_num, dicts in (my_dict | dict2items | groupby('value.redis.port'))
          if (dicts|length) > 1 -%}
      {{ dicts | map(attribute='key') | list }}
      {%- endfor -%}

- debug: var=item
  when: '{{ (bogus | length) > 0 }}'
  with_items: '{{ bogus }}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... But quickly, can you explain why: `{{ my_dict | dict2items | map(attribute="value.redis.port") | list | difference(my_dict | dict2items | map(attribute="value.redis.port") | list | unique) }}` Doesn't work?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, and I'm sorry that I didn't see that "bug" to begin with. I have updated my answer with an explanation, as well as a significantly shorter fact setting

Comment: This code works only for a single repeated element (see what happens when you add a `fourth` element with port 1235 to the source data). For some reason beyond my understanding though, it is enough just to put a comma between the elements in the loop.　・　If (1) there is a Jinja2 for-loop in the template, and (2) Jinja2 is called by Ansible, and (3) the result of the template is a string with comma separated JSON lists, then Jinja2 (or Ansible?) produces a tuple (wraps the whole thing in parentheses).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help Matthew!

I decided it was a bit too ugly having facts, etc. running around, so I decided to just make a filter plugin quickly... Or more to the point, make an addition to the [mathstuff.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/mathstuff.py) file.

Adding:

```
def duplicate(a):
    if isinstance(a, collections.Hashable):
        c = set(a)
    else:
        s = {}
        c = []

        for x in a:
            if x not in s:
                s[x] = 1
            else:
                if s[x] == 1:
                    c.append(x)
                s[x] += 1
    return c
```

In the main body of the document, and adding:

```
'duplicate': duplicate,
```

In to the:

```
class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible math jinja2 filters '''

    def filters(self):
        filters = {
```

So `Jinja2` knows about the filter.

I'm going to make a pull request when I get the time, but should anyone find this in the meantime, or if you don't want to/can't update Ansible, then the following works great:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{ my_dict | dict2items | map(attribute="value.redis.port") | list | duplicate }}'
```

Returns:

```
['1234']
```

I've run some tests with much larger samples, and it works as intended.

**ENJOY!**